# Extracting individual dataframes from a list after transformations (lapply)?

Tags: r

I am learning R and was looking for a way to make the same data transformation across multiple dataframes, for example, recoding a variable that appears in each dataframe, without having to type out the code each time for each dataframe. I created a list of the dataframes and then used lapply() to transform them all in one function, however, the result was stored in a new list. I would like to be able to now extract each one of those list elements into their own dataframes, named the same way as the originals. Does anyone know how to do that?

Here is some example code:

```
testlist<-list(FY2012First,FY2012Last)

testlist<-lapply(testlist, function(q) { 
       q<-mutate(q,
          YearsofServiceCat = 
                ifelse(YearsatAgency<=2, "0-2", 
                ifelse(YearsatAgency>=3 & YearsatAgency<=5,"3-5", 
                ifelse(YearsatAgency>=6 & YearsatAgency<=8,"6-8", 
                ifelse(YearsatAgency>=9,"9 or greater", 
                     "Unknown"))))))}
```

This gives me a new list with each element updated as I want, but now I want to get those elements back into individual dataframes named "FY2012First" and "FY2012Last". I used this to do it individually:

```
FY2012FirstNew<-as.data.frame(list["FY2012First"])
```

However, in FY2012FirstNew, each variable is now named "FY2012First.(variable name)", and I don't want that, they should just be named "(variable name)."

So the question is really two-fold; is there a better way to extract those dataframes, and is there a way to do it without the variable renaming?

Comment: You might consider adding a minimal example, say something on the order of `list( a = list(1:2), b=list(4:5) )`. Probably ought to include library calls needed for loading the hadleyverse functions.

Comment: You can probably get rid of the `ifelse` statements with `cut`. e.g. `mutate(YearsOfServiceCat = cut(YearsatAgency, c(0, 3, 6, 9, 100), c("0-2", "3-5", "6-8", "9+")))`

Comment: Wow, I didn't even know about the cut function, that makes things much simpler, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
data(iris)
data(mtcars)
iris2 = iris
mtcars2 = mtcars
testlist = list(iris2 = iris, mtcars2 = mtcars)

testlist = lapply(testlist, function(dfs){ 
    dfs$new_col = 1
    dfs
})

# datasets are unchanged
str(iris2)
str(mtcars2)
rm(list = names(testlist))
list2env(testlist, baseenv())
# datasets are updated
str(iris2)
str(mtcars2)
```

Comment: Not sure what this does, I didn't get any result out of it :(

Comment: @maccorf It seems that `list2env` doesn't overwrite existing variables. See update with reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

There is probably a better way, but I would use for loop:

```
for (i in 1:length(testlist)) {
    assign(names(testlist)[i], testlist[[i]])
}
```